# Habilitar botão "submit" apenas quando houver alteração de dados

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para habilitar o botão "submit" apenas quando for inserido um dado diferente do que foi retornado do banco. Creio que seja simples, mas sou iniciante na área e não tenho familiaridade com JS. A intenção é que o botão "submit" fique desabilitado caso não haja alteração nos dados.

Segue o código do form:

```
<form action="update_bd.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario" class="input is-large" required="" placeholder="ID" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $linha['id_usuario']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="nome" id="nome" class="input is-large" required="required" placeholder="Nome" autofocus="" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $linha['nome_usuario']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" class="input is-large" required="required" placeholder="Sobrenome"  maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $linha['sobrenome_usuario']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="email" type="email" class="input is-large" required="required" placeholder="E-mail"  maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $linha['email']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="empresa" class="input is-large" required="required" placeholder="Empresa" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $linha['empresa']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="telefone" id="telefone" class="input is-large" required="required" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $linha['telefone']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <div class="select is-fullwidth select is-large">
                                    <select name="acesso" id="acesso" required="">
                                        <?php
                                        
                                        foreach ($acesso as $key => $value) {
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $value['nivel']; ?>
                                            </option>
                                        <?php
                                        }   
                                        ?>

                                        <?php
                                        //exibe valor 0 do array no combobox caso acesso do usuário seja nível 0 (admin)
                                        if ($linha['acesso'] == '0') {
                                            $position = $acesso[0]
                                        ?>
                                            <option selected="" hidden="" value="<?php echo $position['id']; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $position['nivel']; ?>
                                            </option>

                                        <?php   
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                        <?php
                                        //exibe valor 1 do array no combobox caso acesso do usuário seja nível 1 (padrão)
                                        if ($linha['acesso'] == '1') {
                                            $position = $acesso[1]
                                        ?>
                                            <option selected="" hidden="" value="<?php echo $position['id']; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $position['nivel']; ?>
                                            </option>

                                        <?php   
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button is-success is-large">Salvar</button></form>
```

Comment: Como é iniciante, recomendo ler sobre tratamento de eventos dos campos com JS, em especial ao evento `change`. Com isso terá uma noção de como resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Valeu. Vou dar uma pesquisada

Answer (score 0):

Se a necessidade for verificar se o usuário apenas alterou algum campo (mesmo que coloque o mesmo valor), adicione o atributo "disabled" no "button" e acrescente o seguinte código JavaScript:

```
$("input, select, textarea").change(function(){
    $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Recomendo adicionar IDs ou classes em suas tags HTML.